# In TypeScript, how to augment a type declaration with submodules

Tags: typescript

I have a library (here it's highcharts), that have some type definition defined in the package `@types/highcharts` .

in my code I'm importing, for example, `import * as highchartsSolidGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge.src.js';`

This file is not defined in the definition package.

SO I get the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge.src.js'. './front-end/node_modules/highcharts/modules/solid-gauge.src.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  If the 'highcharts' package actually exposes this module, consider sending a pull request to amend 'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/highcharts`
```

Given that :
  - I don't want to copy/paste everything of `@types/highcharts`
  - I dont't want (if possible) to pass an option that would deactivate every check on modules

Is there a way to make this compile without changing the package `@types/highcharts` ?

Highcharts is only an example, the question is essentially: how to augment a type definition to declare a submodule

Comment: Partially answering myself, we can add a magic comment to ts to ignore the problem: `//@ts-ignore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `.d.ts` file in your project and add a [`declare module` statement](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules):

```js
declare module 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge.src.js';
```

This is the minimal declaration. With it, whatever you import from the module will have type `any`.

If you wanted to write some type declarations of your own:

```js
declare module 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge.src.js' {
    export function foo(): string;
}
```

---

> Make sure that the file is included by TypeScript. Usually the easiest way to do this is by specifying the `.d.ts` file in the `include` option of your `tsconfig.json`.